# Mysql multi column count having minimum occurrences values in columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table t1 with 5 columns and 80000 rows :

```
+---+--------+-------+--------+------------+
|id |category|groupe |subject | description|
+---+--------+-------+--------+------------+
|1  |categ1  |group1 |subject1| desc1      |
|2  |categ1  |group2 |subject2| desc2      |
|3  |categ1  |group2 |subject5| desc3      |
|4  |categ2  |group1 |subject5| desc4      |
|5  |categ2  |group3 |subject1| desc5      |
|6  |categ2  |group3 |subject2| desc6      |
|7  |categ3  |group1 |subject1| desc7      |
|8  |categ3  |group1 |subject4| desc8      |
+---+--------+-------+--------+------------+
```

I need to extract rows that have minimum 30 occurrences of values in category AND 30 occurrences of group AND 30 of subject.

This means if "categ3" appears more than 30 times, i need rows with categ3 
same with group and subject.

but when i used the query bellow the final result can have less than 30 categ3 because result has been filtered by group or subject that remove id who have categ3.

You can see an example on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f80ea91e81bb50b4c978e0cd03ca3bea),the good query result count() with 10 occurences have to return 118 rows.

```
        select 
            *
        from 
            t1 
        where
            category in (
                SELECT
                    category
                FROM
                    t1
                GROUP BY
                    category
                HAVING
                    COUNT(category) >= 30
            )
            and 
            groupe in (
                SELECT
                    groupe
                FROM
                    t1
                GROUP BY
                    groupe
                HAVING
                    COUNT(groupe) >= 30
            )
            and 
            subject in (
                SELECT
                    subject
                FROM
                    t1
                GROUP BY
                    subject
                HAVING
                    COUNT(subject) >= 30
            )
```

This query return intersection on ID where category,groupe and subject have 30 occurrences on values,  but this intersection reduce the result count...
this means certain category values count could be reduce to a number less than 30.

for resume,i need 30 occurences in the intersection result.

I think I need to do a recursive filter and have to repeat the loop until input rows is equal to output rows.. But I don't know how to do that... An idea?

Thanks

Comment: `that have minimum 30 occurrences of values` : sorry but can you explain this? You want to return ROW according to the different value in some column? Can you give sample example please? For me one row = one occurence of each column (null or not)

Comment: Note that group is a reserved word in mysql, making it a poor choice as a table/column identifier.

Comment: If it was me, I'd change the parameters of the question. Pretend you want minimum 3 occurrences of values in category AND 3 of group AND 3 of subject. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: thanks for reply, i have edit the question with more details

Comment: Good job with your first question! I hope you'll keep participating on SO.

Answer (score 1):

**Pro tip**: This is a case where describing your requirement takes a lot of thought. As you think about it, think of SQL as a processor of sets of rows.  It is always worthwhile to describe the requirement as carefully as you can, especially when it is as tricky as this one. Often it's helpful to describe the problem domain, rather than just talking about columns and values.

I guess you need the sets of rows meeting your three different criteria (more than x duplicates). You can use a set of `id` values for those rows because they are apparently a primary key (unique).

Here's one set of IDs

```
    SELECT id FROM dataset WHERE category IN (
         SELECT category FROM dataset GROUP BY category HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5))
```

I believe you need all the rows lying in the intersection of those three sets. That is, you want any rows having all three items recurring frequently. You can get that with

```
  id IN set1   AND   id IN set2  AND    id IN set3
```

If you need the union of those sets you can use this instead. This gives you the rows with any of the three items recurring frequently.

```
  id IN set1   OR   id IN set2    OR    id IN set3
```

So [here's the query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=76167dc80ffde226311cc9d28b862ba1).

```
SELECT *
  FROM dataset 
 WHERE id IN (
      SELECT id FROM dataset WHERE category IN (
           SELECT category FROM dataset GROUP BY category HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5))
   AND id IN (
      SELECT id FROM dataset WHERE groupe IN (
           SELECT groupe FROM dataset GROUP BY groupe HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5))
   AND id IN (
      SELECT id FROM dataset WHERE subject IN (
           SELECT subject FROM dataset GROUP BY subject HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5))
```

I used `5` for the repeat threshold. You can use another number.

If you want your *result set* to contain only those rows with at least ten items *in the result set*, rather than in the dataset, you would use this query.

```
select d.* 
from dataset d
join (
select count(*), groupe, category, subject
  from dataset
 group by groupe, category, subject
 having count(*) >= 10
) e ON d.groupe=e.groupe AND d.category = e.category AND d.subject = e.subject
```

Comment: Thanks :), but i ever try this one and if you check the final result, you'll find (for example) only 2 occurences of LDAP so it doesn't respect my limit >=5,

Comment: I guess you want rows from your dataset where all three of your items (category, groupe, subject) occur in your dataset at least n times. `LDAP` itself meets that criterion. But some rows mentioning `LDAP` don't pass the test of the other two items. So they are eliminated.  Perhaps you need to specify your required result more carefully? It's not very productive to ask for help, and then just say "fail" to those who try help you.

Comment: Thanks for time considering my query :),yes i need all 3 occur n time in my final resultset. sorry for my poor description of the issue but my english is not enought good to do better. In french i also have trouble to describe it. but be sure i really appreciate your help, thanks again.

Comment: the solution with join is better for me but it exclude line TTOED/CCSSI/AD because count on couple (TTOED/CCSSI) appear only one time. I need this row because TTOED appear 19 times and CCSSI appear 99 times. I think my issue can't be resolve without make a recursive filter. If i could repeat your first query on the resultset until count input rows is equal to count output rows it will do the job... but i don't know how to do it in mysql...

Answer (score 1):

Add some DISTINCT's, while grouping on the 3 columns.

```
select *
from dataset t
where t.category in (SELECT distinct category FROM dataset GROUP BY category, groupe, subject HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30)
and t.groupe in (SELECT distinct groupe FROM dataset GROUP BY category, groupe, subject HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30) 
and t.subject in (SELECT distinct subject FROM dataset GROUP BY category, groupe, subject HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30)
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=caca05ecac15c27026f2245e2464c70d)*

For reference sake, this query will only select those with a tupple that occurs 30 times or more.
Which will naturally be less that the query above.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dataset 
WHERE (category, groupe, subject) IN (
    SELECT category, groupe, subject
    FROM dataset 
    GROUP BY category, groupe, subject
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I test your query, it's better than mine but it removes some id that i need, in the fiddle example, the expected count(*) in the result must have 118 rows returned, yours return 117...

Comment: @NumZ Huh, 1 missing.  I don't have time right now, so I'll have to check later which one is missing and why.  Or can you already see which one is missing?

Comment: this one missing : TTOED/CCSSI/AD

Comment: this one missing : TTOED/CCSSI/AD, because the couple  "category, groupe" count for CCSSI is only one occurence with TTOED, so less than 5, but it's not true, TTOED, appears 19 times and CCSSI appears 99 times in final result

Comment: you are the boss :)

Comment: Thx, but I think your original query is actually closer to the rule 30+ & 30+ & 30+.  This one just comes closer to your expected 118.  Which is the 117 of my original answer + 1.  (It's an odd puzzle)

Comment: true, after check on my real dataset it seems it's better but there again some troubles....

Comment: I've uncheck the validation, because there is always trouble. i'll try to create another dataset for fiddle example to show the issue. but in the final result i have certain subject less than 30... urf...